# Javascript code doesn't appear on the page

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript lists `<ol>` & `<ul>` that have their distinct divs.  This is my code for both of them:

These are tje// Data for the "HTML Lists" Page

```js
var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];

var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];

window.onload = function(){

    fruits.sort();

    var ol = "<ol>"
    for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
        ol+= "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
    }ol += "</ol>"

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
};

window.onload = function(){
    var ul = "<ul>";

    for(var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++){
        ul += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
        if(directory[i].files) {
          ul += "<ul>";
          for(var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
            ul += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
          }
          ul += "</ul>";
        }
        ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ul;
};
```

```html
<section class="main center">

        <!-- Start your code here -->
        <h2>HTML Lists</h2>

        <h4>Fruit List</h4>
        <div id="olContainer"></div>

        <h4>Directory List</h4>
        <div id="ulContainer"></div>

        <!-- End your code here  -->
    </section>
```

But only the `<ul>` list seems to appear.  I can't get anything for `<ol>`.

Comment: Where is fruits defined?

Comment: I've placed the edits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second onload function does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451244/second-onload-function-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to separe your code in functions and  when load windows  call all function that do you need

```js
var directory = [
        {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
        {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
        {
            type: "directory",
            name: "HTML Files",
            files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"}, {type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]
        },
        {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
        {
            type: "directory",
            name: "JavaScript Files",
            files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"}, {type: "file", name: "file2.js"}, {
                type: "file",
                name: "file3.js"
            }]
        }
    ];
    var fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Pineapples", "Mangos"];

    window.onload = function () {
        ulLoad();
        olLoad();

    };
    function ulLoad() {
        fruits.sort();

        var ol = "<ol>"
        for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            ol += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
        }
        ol += "</ol>"

        var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
    }
    function olLoad() {
        var ul = "<ul>";

        for (var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            ul += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
            if (directory[i].files) {
                ul += "<ul>";
                for (var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
                    ul += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
                }
                ul += "</ul>";
            }
            ul += "</li>";
        }
        ul += "</ul>";

        var myContainer = document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ul;
    }
```

```html
<section class="main center">
    
            <!-- Start your code here -->
            <h2>HTML Lists</h2>

            <h4>Fruit List</h4>
            <div id="olContainer"></div>
    
            <h4>Directory List</h4>
            <div id="ulContainer"></div>
    
            <!-- End your code here  -->
        </section>
```

Comment: Thank you, Enric.  I will accept your answer and give you an upvote.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could I also get an upvote?

Comment: yes, I think it's a correct question @OnurOzbek, take my upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are writing over the `onload` property on the `window` object. This is a function that is called when the browser loads the page.

By assigning it twice, you are overwriting the previous function you assign it with hence only the `ul` list appears.

Instead, you can write those two functions as separate named ones such as `addMyUl` and `addMyOl` and then call those in one main `onload` function defined on `window`.

For example, something like this:

```
function addMyOl(){

  fruits.sort();

  var ol = "<ol>"
  for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
      ol+= "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
  }ol += "</ol>"

  var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
};

function addMyUl(){
  var ul = "<ul>";

  for(var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++){
      ul += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
      if(directory[i].files) {
        ul += "<ul>";
        for(var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
          ul += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
        }
        ul += "</ul>";
      }
      ul += "</li>";
  }
  ul += "</ul>";

  var myContainer = document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ul;
};

window.onload = function() {
  addMyOl();
  addMyUl();
};
```

Alternatively, most likely the best option, is to add the two functions as new [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). For example, you could instead use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // func body
})
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you set `window.onload` twice and the second one overwrites the first one. So you should use `window.addEventListener("load", f)` instead:

```js
var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];

var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];

window.addEventListener("load",function(){

    fruits.sort();

    var ol = "<ol>"
    for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
        ol+= "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
    }ol += "</ol>"

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var ul = "<ul>";

    for(var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++){
        ul += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
        if(directory[i].files) {
          ul += "<ul>";
          for(var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
            ul += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
          }
          ul += "</ul>";
        }
        ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ul;
});
```

```html
<section class="main center">

        <!-- Start your code here -->
        <h2>HTML Lists</h2>

        <h4>Fruit List</h4>
        <div id="olContainer"></div>

        <h4>Directory List</h4>
        <div id="ulContainer"></div>

        <!-- End your code here  -->
    </section>
```

Comment: The code didn't run on my page but I upvoted you anyways since I think that the problem is with my overall project.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are redefining your unload function. In fact, only second function is assigned during execution. Try adding both of them using `addEventListener()` function.

```
window.addEventListener("load", olFunction);
window.addEventListener("load", ulFunction);
```

Answer (score -2):

`window.onload` is overwritten with the second function. You have to write it all in one function.

```
window.onload = function(){
    fruits.sort();

    var ol = "<ol>"
    for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
        ol+= "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
    }ol += "</ol>"

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
    var ul = "<ul>";

    for(var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++){
        ul += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
        if(directory[i].files) {
          ul += "<ul>";
          for(var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
            ul += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
          }
          ul += "</ul>";
        }
        ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ul;
};
```

Comment: No, you don’t have to.

Comment: There is no such requirement.